# '(quote quote) in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, quote

I'm trying to learn scheme by myself. Could anyone tell me why `'(quote quote)` will output `'quote`, and `'(quote 'quote)` will output `''quote`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I highly suggest actually reading the racket documentation: [about the quote keyword](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quote.html?q=quote#(form._((quote._~23~25kernel)._quote), and section 2.4.1 of [the syntax for pairs and lists](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html).

Comment: Just to point out: this is essentially the point of SICP exercise 2.55.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression:

```
'(quote quote)
```

... after expanding `'<something>` to `(quote <something>)` is equivalent to `(quote (quote quote))`, notice that the symbol `quote` is being *quoted* two times, and this expression is evaluated and printed as `''quote`.

On the other hand, this expression:

```
'(quote 'quote)
```

... is equivalent to `(quote (quote (quote quote)))`, notice that the symbol `quote` is being *quoted* three times, and this expression is evaluated and printed as `'''quote`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at (free, online) [How To Design Programs, intermezzo 2](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/i2-3.html). It explains quote in terms of list and cons. If anything in that explanation doesn't make sense, just back up a bit in the textbook.